# How do I modify this function to accept multiple Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression, analytics

I wrote this function and I would like it to accept more than one DF so that the final plot has multiple plotted lines for the predictions and the coef_DF gets completed with the rest of the coefficients.

The function extracts the needed features and target from a much larger dataset to make predictions using a linear regression func, it then makes the model, plots the line over the dataset and returns a df with all the coeficients.

(This is just an exercise.)

```
def prep_model_and_predict(feature, target, dataset, degree):


    # part 1: make a df with relevant format and features 
        # degree >=1

    poly_df=pd.DataFrame()
    poly_df[str(target)] = dataset[str(target)]
    poly_df['power_1']   = dataset[str(feature)]

    #cehck if degree >1
    if degree > 1:
        for power in range(2, degree+1): #loop over reaming deg
            name = 'power_'+str(power)
            poly_df[name]=poly_df['power_1'].apply(lambda x: x**power)

    #part 2: make model and predictions

    features=list(poly_df.columns[1:])
    X=poly_df[features]
    y=poly_df[str(target)]
    model=LinearRegression().fit(X,y)
    predictions=model.predict(X)

    #part 3: put weghts in a nice df

    coef_df=pd.DataFrame()
    coef_df=coef_df.append({"Name":'Intercept', 'Value':model.intercept_},     ignore_index=True)
    coef_df=coef_df.append({'Name':'Power_1',   'Value':model.coef_[0]},   ignore_index=True)

    if degree > 1:
        for degree in range(2, degree+1):
            name = 'Power_' + str(degree)
            coef_df = coef_df.append({"Name":name, 
                                      'Value':'{:.3e}'.format(model.coef_[degree-1])}, ignore_index=True)
    #prt 4: plot it

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(poly_df['power_1'], poly_df[str(target)], '.',
            poly_df['power_1'], predictions, '-')

    ax.set_xlabel('Square footage, living area')
    ax.set_ylabel('Price per Sqft')
    ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(-2,2))

    return coef_df, ax
```

and this is the result:

```
         Name        Value
0   Intercept       506738
1     Power_1  2.71336e-77
2     Power_2    7.335e-39
3     Power_3   -1.850e-44
4     Power_4    8.437e-50
5     Power_5    0.000e+00
6     Power_6    0.000e+00
7     Power_7    3.645e-55
8     Power_8    1.504e-51
9     Power_9    5.760e-48
10   Power_10    1.958e-44
11   Power_11    5.394e-41
12   Power_12    9.404e-38
13   Power_13   -3.635e-41
14   Power_14    4.655e-45
15   Power_15   -1.972e-49
```

[image]

much appreciated!

Comment: Just to understand - You want to pass arbitrary number of `DataFrame` to your function to plot, right?

Comment: @R.p.T yes and to put the results of the model in a df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking for. But I would suggest, next time try to ask a question that is easily produce-able and runnable by other people here in SO.

I have tried to answer your questions. Correct me if I misunderstand your question.

- *Pass arbitrary number of DataFrame to your function and plot it:*

I have created three random dataframes for use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

*The functions that plots them:*

```
def plot_me(*kwargs):
    plt.figure(figsize=(13,9))
    lab_ind = 0
    for i in kwargs:

        plt.plot(i['A'], i['B'], label = lab_ind)
        lab_ind += 1
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

*The result plot you get:*

[image]

---

- Put the results of your model into a `DataFrame`

Regarding your second question, I am not going to concentrate too much on your exact details - for example the name of the columns of your dataframe, etc.

For this particular example I have generated two random arrays:

```
X = np.random.randint(0,50 ,size=(50, 2))
y = np.random.randint(0,2 ,size=(50, 1))
```

Then fit a *LinearRegression model* on this data.

```
model=LinearRegression().fit(X,y)
predictions=model.predict(X)
```

And then add it to a DataFrame:

```
res_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions,columns = ['Value'])
```

And if you print `res_df`

```
    Value
0   0.420395
1   0.459389
2   0.369648
3   0.416058
4   0.644088
5   0.362072
6   0.363157
7   0.468943
.      .
.      .
```

Comment: Thank you this is a good basis to start with and I'll work on being more clear and concise